# Replaceing text with yank in emacs ESS?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I'd like it so that when, in the below, I select the words "-yank here-" and yank the text "!yanked!"...

```
Here is -yank here- an example
```

...I get the following:

```
Here is !yanked! an example
```

...not this:

```
Here is -yank here-!yanked! an example
```

In other buffers I'm able to do this using *delete-selection-mode*, but for some reason I can't get it working in ESS. I can't find anything online, so any advice would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question: enabling CUA-mode (`(cua-mode t)`) will make ESS behave.  then conflicts with the default send-a-single-line-to-R command, but this can be changed (`((cua-rectangle-mark-key [C-S-return])`). It seems to work even if the CUA copy/paste/cut keys are disabled.